# Show the original room name in the chat transcript

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-transcript

Whenever a chatroom is created, it gets some name (and also a description, if the room creator fills it in). Later the room topic can be changed by room owners or moderators, every such event is shown in the room transcript. (As you can check by [searching for messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=room+topic+changed+to) such as "room topic changed to ...".)

Still, the original room name is not shown in any place in the transcript. (Only the subsequent changes are shown.) I am not aware of any way to find out the name which the room got when it was created.

**Suggestion:** When a room is created, include the original room topic in the transcript.

Comment: Do moderators have access to past room names?

Comment: Some chatrooms have had offensive names in the past. I'm pretty sure some poor soul would soon run into one it this were to be implemented.

Answer (score -4):

No, that would be bad idea.

It's against common sense, and against basic user experience: when you change something, you expect it to stay changed and have everyone see the changed name only.

The real issue here is lack of "revisions" like we have for SE posts, and even chat messages, so correct way to fix the problem would be asking to add "chat room revisions".

Comment: Well it is not the changed thing itself, it is a log of changing!